# error :list indices must be integers, not float for median

Tags: python

Trying to find median but keep getting list indices must be integers, not float error and am not sure what to do.

```
sorted_data = sorted(data, key=lambda d:d.all_around_points_earned)
if len(data)%2==0:
    a = sorted_data[len(data)/2]
    b = sorted_data[len(data)/2-1]
    median_val = (a+b)/2
else:
    median_val = sorted_data[(len(data)-1)/2]
print(median_val) # median val
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3, `len(data)/2` will return you a float if `len(data)` is odd. Use `//` instead of `/` to get an integer result.

Comment: i get when i try that :median_val = (a+b)/2
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'

Comment: @Terr_code your value `a` is a `tuple` try `print(a,type(a))` to confirm this.

Comment: @M.T Data(gymnastics_school='Gymnasts of Southern GA', participant_name='Patrick J.', all_around_points_earned=54.801) <class 'main.Data'> is what i get how do i fix this/

Answer (score 0):

The [`statistics` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) is part of the standard library:

```
import statistics

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
statistics.median(data)
```